# Accessing columns inside a record using table alias in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to iterate over the result of a query using a record data type. Nevertheless, if I try to access one column using the table alias defined in the query, I get the following error:

> ERRO:  schema "inv_row" does not exist 
>   CONTEXT: SQL command "SELECT inv_row.s.processor <> inv_row.d.processor" 
>   PL/pgSQL function "teste" line 7 at IF

Here is the code that throws this error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION teste() returns void as $$
DECLARE
    inv_row record;
BEGIN
    FOR inv_row in SELECT * FROM sa_inventory s LEFT JOIN dim_inventory d ON s.macaddr = d.macaddr LOOP
        IF inv_row.s.processor <> inv_row.d.processor THEN
            <do something>;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Is there another way to access a column of a particular table inside a record data type?

Comment: Drop the IF(...) ENDIF,  and add `inv_row.s.processor <> inv_row.d.processor` to the where-clause or join-condition ? BTW: qou cannot assume "three.level.names" in a resultrow. A resultrow only has one level of names. Name them in your query (`select x.y AS a, p.q AS b ...`) , and you will be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately the answer here is relatively simple.  You have to use parentheses to indicate tuples:

```
IF (inv_row.s).processor <> (inv_row.d).processor THEN
```

This is because SQL specifies meaning to the depth of the namespaces and therefore without this PostgreSQL cannot safely determine what this means.  So `inv_row.s.processor` means the `processor` column of the `s` table in the `inv_row` schema.  However `(inv_row.s).processor` means take the `s` column of the inf_row table, treat it as a tuple, and take the `processor` column of that.